# Systematically clean files before compilation

Tags: makefile, ocaml

Here is a part of my `makefile`:

```
all:    $(CMX_DOMAIN) 
        analyze

clean:
    rm -rf */*.o */*.cmo */*.cmi */*.cmx */*.cma */*.cmxa */*.cmo */*.cmi */*.annot \
      $(AUTOGEN) */*~ */*.log */*.output depend analyze print batch
```

After modifying the code, I need to type `make clean` before launching `make`. Otherwise,  very often there is a problem of inconsistent dependencies.

Now I would like to amend the `makefile` so that `clean` is done systematically before each call of `all`. I then write

```
all:    clean
        $(CMX_DOMAIN) 
        analyze
```

When I launch `make`, after the cleaning of the files, it gives me an error `/bin/bash: values/consts_bool.cmx: No such file or directory`, where `values/consts_bool` is the first component on the list of files. That is odd, because it is normal that this file doesn't exist, that is supposed to be generated afterwards.

Could anyone help?

Comment: You should be fixing the "problem of inconsistent dependencies", not trying to add a `clean` rule.  A proper makefile will always rebuild exactly what is out of date, and not rebuild what is not out of date.  If your makefile is not doing that then it's not written correctly.  As tripleee says, if you want to clean everything every time then a makefile is completely useless to you.  Just write a shell script that compiles your code from scratch every time and forget about make altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
all: clean $(CMX_DOMAIN)
```

on one line.

I don't particularly recommend this, because removing all built files negates the primary purpose of Make.  If you don't want to keep files around, why are you using Make?

As a temporary fix while working on the build infra, it might make some sense, though.

Comment: I am not sure that works... I thought `clean` deletes everything which is good enough... adding `$(CMX_DOMAIN)$` on one line means only deleting `.cmx` or deleting evertying except `.cmx`?

Comment: No, that's not at all what it means to add two prerequisites to a target.  It means that before the `all` target can be considered up to date, both the `clean` and `$(CMX_DOMAIN)` targets must be built.  Although this solution will work fine for serial builds, it will break badly for parallel builds.